# Select all criteria except one

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I did a macro in VBA that selects all values except zero and it came down this way.

```
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$11:$P$101").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("1" _
            , "10", "100", "110", "118", "119", "120", "14", "152", "16", "18", "19", "2", "209", "21", _
            "212", "25", "280", "3", "31", "34", "36", "39", "390", "4", "5", "54", "6", "67", "7", "70", _
            "74", "8", "84", "94", "97"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But those values change but one thing is for sure I need to select all of them except zero.
Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: greater than zero?

Answer (score 2):

If those values are numbers, probably you need something like:

`Criteria1:=">0"`

IF those values are strings **and you got only single zeros** like `0` and not values like `0123` then:

`Criteria1:="<>0*"`

In both cases you need `Operator:=xlAnd`

Comment: If there's only one criterion, then `xlAnd` is probably not appropriate for `Operator`?

Comment: @BigBen I see your point but when applying a filter with condition "greater than" by default it's `xlAnd`. Anyways, it's an optional argument and  **it can be deleted from code** but my point adding it was to makre sure OP does not use option `xlFilterValues`